# Using Heroku Vulcan to build lib with dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, build-process

**Mission**: Make a build of [ffmpegthumbnailer](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpegthumbnailer/) that can be vendored with a Rails app and deployed to Heroku's Cedar stack.

Process so far:

1. [success] Build ffmpeg with [Vulcan](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan) (using [this guide](https://gist.github.com/coopermaruyama/3963576)) and upload to S3
2. [failed] Build ffmpegthumbnailer with ffmpeg as dependency.

Using command:

```
$ vulcan build -v -s ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8 -d http://s3.amazonaws.com/remoting-io-cdn/heroku-building-lib/ffmpeg
```

I get the following (see error at the bottom):

```
Packaging local directory... done
Uploading source package... done
Building with: ./configure --prefix /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0 && make install
downloading http://s3.amazonaws.com/remoting-io-cdn/heroku-building-lib/ffmpeg
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking whether /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64 accepts --as-needed... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for FFMPEG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libavutil libavformat libavcodec >= 52.26.0 libswscale) were not met:

No package 'libavutil' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libswscale' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables FFMPEG_CFLAGS
and FFMPEG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
bin/vulcan-make:69:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /app/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0 (Errno::ENOENT)
    from bin/vulcan-make:69:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from bin/vulcan-make:18:in `chdir'
    from bin/vulcan-make:18:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
    from bin/vulcan-make:17:in `<main>'
>> Downloading build artifacts to: /tmp/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.tgz
   (available at http://remoting-io-lib-builder.herokuapp.com/output/e25f3591-ce65-433d-a45a-15bd7ea36109)
```

What does that error message mean? And what should I do differently to compile it correctly?

Comment: I ended up hiring a freelancer. Do u need a compiled version of ffmpegthumbnailer?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing; how did you end up installing ffmpegthumbnailer on heroku?

Comment: Here you go sir: https://github.com/JonasNielsen/ffmpegthumbnailer

Comment: great!  I had been working hours trying to get ffmpegthumbnailer installed, so thanks for putting this together.

Comment: I tried installing using the instructions you provided on github but it didn't work for me.  I submitted an issue about it here: https://github.com/JonasNielsen/ffmpegthumbnailer/issues/1 Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer can be build with Vulcan following the [steps explained here](https://github.com/JonasNielsen/ffmpegthumbnailer#how-to-compile-libs)

A sample app with vendored ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer is available here: https://github.com/JonasNielsen/ffmpegthumbnailer Check out the Heroku configuration instructions in the readme.

Comment: I ran into issues trying to install ffmpethumbnailer based on your documentation. github.com/JonasNielsen/ffmpegthumbnailer/issues/1 If you have any suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems

1. You need to build it's dependencies first (libavutil, libavformat, libavcodec, libswscale)
2. The thing that you downloaded is not actually the build (the build never happened it failed at configure) It is just the artifacts from the progress that *was* made.
3. I have had much more success with hammer (https://github.com/hone/hammer) then vulcan in terms of reusability.

To solve this you are going to need to go through this same process for each of the dependancies then in your build script pull them down from s3 extract them and make sure that they are in your path or lib directory.

I have also found that `heroku run bash` is invaluable when hacking on these things because it allows you to tinker with your environment more.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'll give that a try. I also checked out hammer. It looks interesting. But how do you provide dependencies?

Comment: I genrally curl them down. So if I need an external dependency I will go build it in it's on hammer project then download the binaries with curl into the project.