# getting ffmpegthumbnailer to work on heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg

Has anyone gotten ffmpegthumbnailer to work on heroku?  The only documentation I can find online is here:

[Using Heroku Vulcan to build lib with dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091934/using-heroku-vulcan-to-build-lib-with-dependency)

And it seems like it was never answered.

As I try to install ffmpegthumbnailer, I get the error:

```
checking for FFMPEG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libavutil libavformat libavcodec >= 52.26.0 libswscale) were not met:

No package 'libavutil' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libswscale' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables FFMPEG_CFLAGS
and FFMPEG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

I do have ffmpeg installed, though, which I can check with **heroku which ffmpeg**, which returns **vendor/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg**

I tried adding environment variables FFMPEG_CFLAGS and FFMPEG_LIBS:

```
FFMPEG_CFLAGS:   bin:vendor/ffmpeg/include:vendor/libav/include
FFMPEG_LIBS:     vendor/ffmpeg/lib:vendor/libav/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: vendor/ffmpeg/lib:/usr/local/lib
PATH:            bin:vendor/ffmpeg/bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

**How do I get my Heroku app to recognize my installation of ffmpeg when I install ffmpegthumbnailer?**

Answer (score 2):

Here are the full instructions for how to install ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer on a heroku app.  It took me several weeks to finally get this working, so I hope this helps other people out!

https://gist.github.com/ttseng/7682321